# Translate IPv4 address to IPv6 mapped address

Tags: c++, sockets, ipv6

I am trying to implement dual stack sockets, which wilol work with both IPv6 and IPv4. I opened a socket with `AF_INET6` family and set `IPV6_V6ONLY` to zero. So I actually should be able to work with both types of sockets. But when I am connecting to IPv4 address I got invalid argument error. I tried to add `::ffff:` prefix to address, but it did not work.

Is there are a way to gently tanslate ipv4 address to ipv6 in order to be able to work with ipv6 socket ?

Cheers.

Comment: This seems like it ought to work. Can you show some code?

Comment: I also translated a port and now it seems to work, but another problem came up - following calls to getnameinfo and recv are returning "No such file or directory" error.